# TinyMCE add bbcode

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="appendBBCode('youtube','ContentArea')">[youtube]</button>
<br>
<div class="form-group field-boats-content required">
    <label class="control-label" for="boats-content">Content</label>
    <textarea id="ContentArea" name="Boats[content]" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
```

Now, when tinyMCE is not initialized, when it's just "pure" textarea this function below works as expected and on the other hand, when tinyMCE is initialized then nothing happens, and console in chrome is not showing any kind of errors, too.

Here's my function:

```
function appendBBCode(tag, containerID) {
   var Field = document.getElementById(containerID);
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
   Field.value += '[' + tag + ']' + '[/' + tag + ']';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying `textarea` directly you need to do it through `tinyMCE` [setContent()](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API4:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent) function:

```
tinyMCE.get(containerID).setContent('updated content goes here....');
```

You can extract currently selected text with:

```
tinyMCE.get(containerID).selection.getContent();
```